# Laravel subdomain accepts other similar subdomain which are not even pointed to the project

Tags: laravel, subdomain, multi-tenant

I have pointed some subdomains to my project in laravel, some similar subdomain exists on the same server, but pointed to other projects.
Still sometimes they point to my project.
How to resolve this issue?
route structure-
I have a wildcard route-

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.website.com'), function () {

    Route::get('/', function ($subdomain) {



    });
});
```

My subdomain which are pointed to this project are-
Xyz.website.com, abc.website.com
but other links like feh.website.com which are pointed to other projects are sometimes pointing to my project.
Please help for above scenario .

Answer (score -1):

I thought it depends on your web server config. 
If you use nginx as web server, you should declare the server name:

```
{
    ...
    servername xyz.website.com abc.website.com
    ...
}
```

If you get some else url point to your project like `feh.website.com`, that maybe because you did not declare settings for `feh.website.com` and it will go to your first virtual server.